# The value attribute of <option> inside <select> is not added through the $.each jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I get a JSON response as follows.

```
{
   "stateTables":[
      {
         "stateId":15,
         "stateName":"kkkkkkkk"
      },
      {
         "stateId":34,
         "stateName":"qwqw"
      },
      {
         "stateId":61,
         "stateName":"xx"
      },
      {
         "stateId":66,
         "stateName":"aaa"
      }
   ]
}
```

The JavaScript function that receives this response is as follows.

```
var timeout;
var request;

function poplateStateListe(id)
{
    if(!request)
    {
        if(id===null||id===""||id===undefined||isNaN(id))
        {
            var options = $("#state");
            options.find('option').remove().end();
            options.append($("<option/>").val("").text("Select"));

            alert("Please select an appropriate option.");
            return;
        }

        request = $.ajax({
            datatype:"json",
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: {"id": id},
            url: "PopulateStateList.action",
            success: function(response)
            {
                var list = response.stateTables;
                var options = $("#state");

                options.find('option').remove().end();
                options.append($("<option/>").val("").text("Select"));

                $.each(list, function() {
                    options.append($("<option/>").val(this.stateId).text(this.stateName));
                });
            },
            complete: function()
            {
                timeout = request = null;
            },
            error: function(request, status, error)
            {
                if(status!=="timeout"&&status!=="abort")
                {
                    alert(status+" : "+error);
                }
            }
        });
        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            if(request)
            {
                request.abort();
                alert("The request has been timed out.");
            }
        }, 30000);
    }
}
```

I write this response to a `<select>` list. I however, generate this list as follows.

```
<select name="entity.stateId" id="state">
    <option>Select</option>
    <option>kkkkkkkk</option>
    <option>qwqw</option>
    <option>xx</option>
    <option>aaa</option>
</select>
```

The `value` attribute of `<option>` is not added. The actual list should have been.

```
<select name="entity.stateId" id="state">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="15">kkkkkkkk</option>
    <option value="34">qwqw</option>
    <option value="61">xx</option>
    <option value="66">aaa</option>
</select>
```

Why is not the `value` attribute added through the `$.each` function

```
$.each(list, function() {
    options.append($("<option/>").val(this.stateId).text(this.stateName));
});
```

inside the `success` handler of the given JavaScript function? I'm missing something obvious here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with using `.attr()` instead of `.val()`

```
$.each(list, function() {
    options.append($("<option/>").attr('value', this.stateId).text(this.stateName));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possible syntax is :

```
$.each(list, function() {
    options.append($("<option/>", {value: this.stateId}).text(this.stateName));
});
```

Hope it helps.